# Unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-merge

[image]

I am facing this issue, can someone help to validate this merge statement?

```
MERGE INTO WC_FNHLDNG_D T1 
USING (SELECT distinct ROW_WID, CONTACT_WID
        FROM W_ASSET_D 
         WHERE X_TYPE_CD='Fin Account')T2 
ON (T1.ASSET_WID=T2.ROW_WID) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
SET T1.CONTACT_WID=T2.CONTACT_WID;
```

Comment: Instead of posting an image of your code, please copy paste it directly in your question.

Comment: Images of code or SQL are useless. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of many reasons why. SQL is plain text, and it can be copied, pasted and properly formatted into your post here very easily. Please [edit] to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Acquire locks on WC_FNHLDNG_D and W_ASSET_D before attempting the MERGE operation.

Answer (score 0):

The rule of merge is that there must be no more than one row in the USING subquery which matches a row in the target table.

Your subquery is this:

> `SELECT distinct ROW_WID, CONTACT_WID
>   FROM W_ASSET_D`

So if there is more than one different CONTACT_WID for a given ROW_WID it will return multiple rows for the ROW_WID. The DISTINCT clause won't help, because the CONTACT_WID are different.

The fact that your statement hurls `ORA-30926` suggests this is the state of your data. Oracle doesn't know which W_ASSET_D.CONTACT_WID is the right one to merge into WC_FNHLDNG_D so it gives up. The solution to rewrite the USING subquery so it returns only one CONTACT_WID per ROW_WID.

You should have some additional business rules you can add in a WHERE clause. But as a last resort you can use an aggregating function, e.g.

```
USING (SELECT ROW_WID, max( CONTACT_WID) as CONTACT_WID
       FROM W_ASSET_D 
       WHERE X_TYPE_CD='Fin Account'
       group by ROW_WID
   )T2
```

This is better than choosing a random CONTACT_WID but not by much :)